# WP7 - Not picking up embedded fonts

Tags: windows-phone-7, fonts

I have been trying to use some custom fonts within my WP7 app.

I followed the example as per http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/24/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-24-embedding-fonts/ but in my project it simply will not pick up the custom font.
I have downloaded the sample project in this example and this one does work okay.

So, I have now  used the same font used in  there, and included in my project.  I have ensured that the properties on the file are identical (Build Action = 'Content' and Copy To Output Directory = "Always")

I have used in my XAML in exactly the same way i.e.

```
  FontFamily="Fonts/DigitalDream.ttf#Digital Dream" FontSize="24"
```

But to no avail.  The custom font is just ignored.  Is there something that I am missing, or a setting .. anything that would allow this  to work in one project, but not another?

I have discovered that it will work if my XAML page is defined at the root level, i.e. immediately under the project, but in my case I have it in a 'Views' folder.

My understanding was  that 
     FontFamily="/Fonts/DigitalDream.ttf#Digital Dream" FontSize="24"

should start  at the root folder of the project?

- thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom fonts can be a little tricky. I spent several hours once trying to embed an .otf font only to find that it just didn't seem to be doable.

You're on the right track, though. A .ttf font should be embedable. It's hard to get the right combination of paths and filenames to make the font work, though.

The easiest way I've found to handle some of these more difficult "magic string" type of situations in XAML is to let Expression Blend do the heavy lifting.

Here's a [blog post](http://blog.markarteaga.com/CustomFontsInWindowsPhone7WithExpressionBlend.aspx) about using Blend to embed fonts. The nice thing about using Blend is that it gives you some visual indications that things are set up correctly--i.e. you can see the font you want in the font selection menu. This is what finally clued me in on the .otf issue. I couldn't see the font in Blend.

And here's an example of a custom font that I've used in one of my apps:

```
<TextBlock Name="MyTextblock"
   FontFamily="/MyAppName;component/fonts/Fonts.zip#Segoe UI Mono">
```

That's `FontFamily` URI is a pain to get right. I'm pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: Yes - thanks - I am sure you are on the right track..  and I have updated the query.   The issue  is what path should I be using.  I have tried a number of combinations, based upon  what I have read... but no joy.

Comment: Did you try the `/MyAppName;component/` prefix? That should take you to the root directory. Good catch noticing that it works in pages at the root level, by the way.

Comment: If you can repro the problem in a sample app, I'd be glad to take a look at it. Also, check to make sure the `MyAppName` value matches the assembly name for your app. That will probably be the same as the project name, but they might not match if you've renamed it.

Comment: I think the answer is in here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx   but I just can't get it to work

Comment: That would be appreciated.  How can I provide you the sample app?  - thanks

Comment: If you have a Dropbox account, you could post a .zip file in your Public folder. Or post it in Windows Skydrive, or some other file sharing service. I'll take a look.

Comment: Ok - I created a sample app and it all worked.  My project has the textblock control within a Data Template.  Ran the app again and it worked fine, although there is a difference in that inside of VS, if the textblock is outside of a template its shows immediately, but with it inside, it did not show until I ran the emulator.  Pretty sure I had tried this previously...but not 100% certain.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sometimes custom fonts don't show in the VS designer. Also, sometimes there are display difference between what you see in Visual Studio vs. Blend vs. the emulator. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having the same problem. I followed everything to the dot and still I wasn't able to embed one particular font. So I created a new project and tried embedding the font there. Still no luck. I then tried embedding some other font. And lo and behold, as soon as I typed the FontFamily attribute, I could see that it had embedded. This was particularly odd since I didn't have to change any properties of the font.

I opened the project in Blend and clicked on the font property box to the right. It took a few seconds and then it embedded the font I was having problems with in the first place.