# WP7 Binding a font in Application.Resources of App.xaml

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

In App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
```

Let's say I have

```
<FontFamily x:Key="SomeFontName">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
```

How to make

```
<FontFamily x:Key="SomeFontName">{BINDING ?????}</FontFamily>
```

Or may be there is another way of setting a FontFamily with Binding in App.xaml?

Comment: I guess you cannot bind the external font in app.xaml but you use embedded fonts from your resources. Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657146/wp7-not-picking-up-embedded-fonts

Comment: Yes, I know how to use embedded fonts. The question is only how to use binding inside the <tag>...</tag>. Or how to set it another way?